# Use Room's TypeConverters on multiple fields

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, kotlin-android-extensions, typeconverter

I am currently developing a small Android application and I am facing a problem about using a same `TypeConverters` on two fields.
Here are the fields I have :

```
@TypeConverters(DateConverters::class)
@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "create_date")
var createDate: Date

@TypeConverters(DateConverters::class)
@NonNull
@ColumnInfo(name = "update_date")
var updateDate: Date
```

`create_date` and `update_date` are both `Date` objects into my model class, but they are stored as `String` into the database. In order to do that, I have created a `DateConverters` class :

```
object DateConverters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun toDate(value: String): Date {
        val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(PATTERN, Locale.getDefault())
        return simpleDateFormat.parse(value)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun toString(value: Date): String {
        val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(PATTERN, Locale.getDefault())
        return simpleDateFormat.format(value)
    }
}
```

But when I try to run my application, I have to following error message :

`error: DateConverters() has private access in DateConverters`

I also add that before, I only had a `create_date` field and I had no problem on app run.

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong ?

Thank you in advance !

Comment: Add @JvmStatic to the two methods in DateConverters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the problem can be in either using `object` instead of `class` or in methods names of converter.
I recommend you to rewrite `DateConverters` in the following way:

```
class DateConverters {
    @TypeConverter
    fun fromString(value: String): Date {
        val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(PATTERN, Locale.getDefault())
        return simpleDateFormat.parse(value)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun dateToString(value: Date): String {
        val simpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat(PATTERN, Locale.getDefault())
        return simpleDateFormat.format(value)
    }
}
```

Moreover, I recommend you to store values as Long not as String as it is described in [samples](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data) and then use `SimpleDateFormat` in non-data level.

Comment: Hi @Valerii, thank you for you answer, it solved my problem ! The reason why I decided to store it in String format is because I wanted to keep track of the timezone as well but I think I will just reconsider it later. Thanks again !